# Correctly calling setGridWidth on a jqGrid inside a jQueryUI Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a jQueryUI dialog (`#locDialog`) which has a jqGrid (`$grid`) inside it.  When the Dialog opens (initially, but it gets called whenever it opens), I want the `$grid` to resize to the size of the `$locDialog`.  When I do this initially, I get scrollbars inside the grid (not inside the dialog).

If I debug the code, I see the width of the `$grid` is 677.  So, I call `setGridWidth()` again and check the width and now I have 659, which is 18px less, which is the size of the scroll area for the jqGrid (Dun-dun-dun..)

When I rezie the dialog, I resize the grid as well, and everything is happy - no scrollbars, except where necessary.

My dialog init code:

```
$locDialog = $('#location-dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    position: ['center', 100],
    width: 700,
    height:500,
    resizable: true,
    buttons: {
                "Show Selected": function() {alert($('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow'));},
                "OK": function() {$(this).dialog('close');},
                "Cancel": function() {$(this).dialog('close');}
             },
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $grid.setGridHeight($(this).height()-54); 
          // No idea why 54 is the magic number here
        $grid.setGridWidth($(this).width(), true);
    },
    close: function(event, ui) {

    },
    resizeStop: function(event, ui) {
        $grid.setGridWidth($locDialog.width(), true);
        $grid.setGridHeight($locDialog.height()-54);
    }
});
```

I am curious if anyone has seen this before.  Really, it isn't the end of the world if I initially have unnecessary scrollbars at first, but it is just odd that when I call setGridWidth initially, it doesn't take into account the scroll area of 18px.

As far as the magical number 54, that is the number I had to subtract from the height of the dialog value to get the grid to render without unnecessary scrollbars.

---

I think it may be a timing issue, though this doesn't make a lot of sense.  Perhaps I should call an event once the grid is completely loaded.  This may ensure it calculates its width correctly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are some cases, where jqGrid calculate the width a little incorrect. Mostly I have problems with grid width, but in some cases on IE6 also with the height. So I have to write a small function to fix the problem.

```
var fixGridWidth = function (grid) {
    var gviewScrollWidth = grid[0].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.scrollWidth;
    var mainWidth = jQuery('#main').width();
    var gridScrollWidth = grid[0].scrollWidth;
    var htable = jQuery('table.ui-jqgrid-htable', grid[0].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode);
    var scrollWidth = gridScrollWidth;
    if (htable.length > 0) {
        var hdivScrollWidth = htable[0].scrollWidth;
        if ((gridScrollWidth < hdivScrollWidth))
            scrollWidth = hdivScrollWidth; // max (gridScrollWidth, hdivScrollWidth)
    }
    if (gviewScrollWidth != scrollWidth || scrollWidth > mainWidth) {
        var newGridWidth = (scrollWidth <= mainWidth)? scrollWidth: mainWidth;  // min (scrollWidth, mainWidth)
        // if the grid has no data, gridScrollWidth can be less then hdiv[0].scrollWidth
        if (newGridWidth != gviewScrollWidth)
            grid.jqGrid("setGridWidth", newGridWidth);
    }
};

var fixGridHeight = function (grid) {
    var gviewNode = grid[0].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    //var gview = grid.parent().parent().parent();
    //var bdiv = jQuery("#gview_" + grid[0].id + " .ui-jqgrid-bdiv");
    var bdiv = jQuery(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv", gviewNode);
    if (bdiv.length) {
        var delta = bdiv[0].scrollHeight - bdiv[0].clientHeight;
        var height = grid.height();
        if (delta !== 0 && height && (height-delta>0)) {
            grid.setGridHeight(height-delta);
        }
    }
};

var fixGridSize = function (grid) {
    this.fixGridWidth(grid);
    this.fixGridHeight(grid);
};
```

In this code `"main"` is the id of parent div inside of which the grid will be created. In the code I test (`scrollWidth > mainWidth`) whether the width of `"main"` allow increasing of jqGrid width.

Correct place to call this function is inside of `loadComplete`:

```
loadComplete: function() {
    var gr = jQuery('#list');
    fixGridSize(gr);
}
```

and inside of `"done"`, if you use `'columnChooser'` if use use `Query('#list').jqGrid('columnChooser');`

(in this example I use also `'gridResize'`.)

Comment: I will definitely give this a look, Oleg - many thanks for the code.  I'm not too worried about it at this point as the problem only occurs right when the user opens a dialog.  Once they resize/reload, it fixes itself.  Again, likely a timing issue.  Thanks again :D

Comment: @Oleg: Can you look at something similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292341/horizontal-scroll-bar-in-jqgrid-when-needed)

Comment: I know this is an old answer but... I've tried to use this code but it doesn't work properly. I've used @Oleg's `fixGridWidth` function and yes, it resizes de grid. But columns remain with the same size so there is half of the grid empty, columns don't resize. Do you know how to resize columns too?

Comment: @Isthar: You should post new question where you describe detailed what you do and what problem you have.

Comment: @Oleg: can you help me in one point. I have used the same code. and I'm also calling `fixGridSize(gr);` on `window.onresize` event, width is getting auto calculated that good but **height is getting reduced** when I do _Zoom Out_ (i.e. on `CTRL -`).

Comment: @RaunakGupta: Sorry, but the answer is written more as 6 years ago. The problem not exist in current versions on jqGrid. I recommend you to try the current code of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) - the fork of jqGrid, which I develop. If you would still have any problems you can ask new question and include the demo, which reproduces the problem. You should describe the test case too, including the information about the web browser, which you use in the tests.

Comment: thanks @Oleg, for such a quick response, I'm using the latest commercial version, I made a dirth fix, and i change one line at it is working except Zoom 50%. `var height = 800;//grid.height();`

Comment: @RaunakGupta: Sorry, I develop alternative fork, which I can be used free jqGrid completely free of charge. I can't provide any support of Gurrido jqGrid JS. You can try (at least temporary) to replace URLs to jqGrid files to URLs from CDN (see [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)) and verify whether your problem is *common* for both forks of jqGrid. In the case I could try to help you to fix the problem. An example of the demo is http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/andm1299/26/

Comment: @RaunakGupta: See [here](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) some more examples of the usage free jqGrid.

Comment: @Oleg: yup in your case it is working fine, I think I messed up totally at my end I think I put many ingredients from many version, and today app has been made live; So client asked for fix then I'll move totally to your example.  **thank you** very much.