# JQgrid not sizing properly in IE8

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

For some reason I cannot seem to get IE8 to display my jqgrid right as you can see below. This isn't the only grid that doesn't display properly. I have another one in my project that renders just like the one below :(. Needless to say, I tried all sort of column widths, tried turning the scrollbars off etc etc. but nothing seems to improve the situation.

Am I missing something obvious ?

I am using the very latest JQgrid version 3.8.

Firefox:
[image]

Explorer:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly the problem exist in CSS which you use (for example standard CSS generated by ASP.MVC MVC). Different web browsers interpret CSS inheritance differently. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686043/correctly-calling-setgridwidth-on-a-jqgrid-inside-a-jqueryui-dialog/2696776#2696776) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091200/jqgrid-horizontal-scrollbar/3091337#3091337). Probably the usage of increased `cellLayout` parameter or the function [fixGridWidth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686043/correctly-calling-setgridwidth-on-a-jqgrid-inside-a-jqueryui-dialog/2696776#2696776) inside of [loadComplete](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events) could solve your problem.

Comment: Fiddling around with cellLayout fixed it. The magic number apparently was 10. Now it looks nice. Thanks !