# jqGrid - resize last column

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqGRid 4.4.1.

Here is the sample code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>SubGrid Real Data</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.3.2/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<style>
    .groupColumn {
            background-color: #E3E3D7 !important;
            border: 1px solid #F4F4e5;
            font-weight: bold; !important;
    }
    .lockedColumn {
            background-color: #E3E3D7 !important;
            border: 1px solid #F4F4e5;
    }

    .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv {
        position: relative; 
        margin: 0em; 
        padding:0; 
        /*overflow: auto;*/ 
        overflow-x:hidden; 
        overflow-y:auto; 
        text-align:left;
    }

    .ui-jqgrid .ui-subgrid td.subgrid-data {
        border-top: 0 none !important;
        border-right: 0 none !important;
        border-bottom: 0 none !important;
    }
    .ui-jqgrid .ui-subgrid span.ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-sw {
                background-color: #FFFFFF !important; 
                background-image: none !important;
                border: 0px 0px 1px 1px;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
    $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    /*global $ */
    /*jslint browser: true, eqeq: true, plusplus: true */
    $(function () {

        "use strict";
        var colModelData =[{"classes":"groupColumn","name":"itemName","editable":false},
                {"width":"100","name":"24394","editable":false},
                {"width":"100","name":"24390","editable":false},
                {"width":"100","name":"24387","editable":false},
                {"width":"100","name":"24386","editable":false},
                {"width":"100","name":"24385","editable":false},
                {"width":"100","name":"24383","editable":false},
                {"width":"100","name":"24369","editable":false},
                {"width":"100","name":"24306","editable":false}],
            subColModelData =[
            {"classes":"groupColumn","name":"itemName","editable":false},
                {"width":"99","name":"24394","editable":false},
                {"width":"100","name":"24390","editable":false},
                {"width":"100","name":"24387","editable":false},
                {"width":"100","name":"24386","editable":false},
                {"width":"100","name":"24385","editable":false},
                {"width":"100","name":"24383","editable":false},
                {"width":"100","name":"24369","editable":false},
                {"width":"98","name":"24306","editable":false}],
            colNamesArray = ["Name","12/21/2012","12/10/2012","12/03/2012","11/27/2012","11/15/2012","11/12/2012","11/09/2012","10/15/2012"],
        myData = [{"id":"group1","itemName":"Miscellaneous",
            "subGridData":[
            {"id":0,"itemName":"NNNNNN","24369":"","24387":"","24394":"","24306":"","24390":"","24385":"","24386":"","24383":""},
            {"id":1,"itemName":"EEEEEEE","24369":"","24387":"","24394":"","24306":"","24390":"","24385":"","24386":"","24383":""},
            {"id":2,"itemName":"7777777","24369":"","24387":"","24394":"","24306":"6.3","24390":"","24385":"","24386":"","24383":""},
            {"id":3,"itemName":"KKKKKK","24369":"","24387":"","24394":"","24306":"68","24390":"","24385":"","24386":"","24383":""},
            {"id":4,"itemName":"JJJJJ","24369":"","24387":"","24394":"","24306":"160","24390":"","24385":"","24386":"","24383":""},
            {"id":5,"itemName":"TTTTT","24369":"","24387":"","24394":"","24306":"77","24390":"","24385":"","24386":"","24383":""},{"id":6,"itemName":"LLLLLL","24369":"","24387":"","24394":"","24306":"88","24390":"","24385":"","24386":"","24383":""},{"id":7,"itemName":"RRRRR","24369":"","24387":"","24394":"","24306":"2:!","24390":"","24385":"","24386":"","24383":""},{"id":8,"itemName":"AAAAAA","24369":"","24387":"","24394":"","24306":"","24390":"","24385":"","24386":"","24383":""},{"id":9,"itemName":"CCCCC","24369":"","24387":"","24394":"","24306":"","24390":"","24385":"","24386":"","24383":""},{"id":10,"itemName":"HHHHH","24369":"","24387":"","24394":"","24306":"","24390":"","24385":"","24386":"","24383":""},{"id":11,"itemName":"OOOO","24369":"","24387":"","24394":"","24306":"","24390":"","24385":"","24386":"","24383":""},{"id":12,"itemName":"PPPP","24369":"","24387":"","24394":"","24306":"","24390":"","24385":"","24386":"","24383":""},{"id":13,"itemName":"DDDDD","24369":"","24387":"","24394":"","24306":"","24390":"","24385":"","24386":"","24383":""},{"id":14,"itemName":"GGGG","24369":"","24387":"","24394":"","24306":"","24390":"","24385":"","24386":"","24383":""},{"id":15,"itemName":"UBBBBB","24369":"","24387":"","24394":"","24306":"","24390":"","24385":"","24386":"","24383":""},{"id":16,"itemName":"UUUUU","24369":"","24387":"","24394":"","24306":"","24390":"","24385":"","24386":"","24383":""},{"id":17,"itemName":"NNNN","24369":"","24387":"","24394":"","24306":"","24390":"","24385":"","24386":"","24383":""},{"id":18,"itemName":"CCCC","24369":"","24387":"","24394":"","24306":"","24390":"","24385":"","24386":"","24383":""},{"id":19,"itemName":"SSSSS","24369":"","24387":"","24394":"","24306":"","24390":"","24385":"","24386":"","24383":""},{"id":20,"itemName":"FFFF","24369":"","24387":"","24394":"","24306":"","24390":"","24385":"","24386":"","24383":""},{"id":21,"itemName":" ","24369":"","24387":"","24394":"","24306":"","24390":"","24385":"","24386":"","24383":""},{"id":22,"itemName":"zzzzzz","24369":"","24387":"","24394":"","24306":"","24390":"","24385":"","24386":"","24383":""},
            {"id":23,"itemName":"NLNLNLNL","24369":"XXXX","24387":"","24394":"","24306":"I want to see this data","24390":"","24385":"","24386":"","24383":""}]}];
        $("#list").jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            data: myData,
            colNames: colNamesArray,
            colModel: colModelData,
            gridview: true,
            autoWidth:true,
            //height: "100%",
            height:"350px",
            width: "100%",
            caption: "Create subgrid from local data",
            subGrid: true,
            subGridOptions: {
                    reloadOnExpand: false
            },
            subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridDivId, parentRowId) {
                    var $subgrid = $("<table id='" + subgridDivId + "_t'></table>");
                    $subgrid.appendTo("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(subgridDivId));
                    var data = $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", parentRowId);
                    $subgrid.jqGrid({
                            datatype: "local",
                            data: $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", parentRowId).subGridData,
                            colModel:subColModelData,
                            autoWidth:true,
                            width: "100%",
                            height: "100%",
                            autoencode: true,
                            gridview: true,
                            rowNum: 200

                    });
            $subgrid.closest("div.ui-jqgrid-view")
                    .children("div.ui-jqgrid-hdiv").hide();
            },
            resizeStop: function (newWidth, index) {
                // grid.dragEnd()
                var widthChange = this.newWidth - this.width,
                    $theGrid = $(this.bDiv).find(">div>.ui-jqgrid-btable"),
                    $subgrids = $theGrid.find(">tbody>.ui-subgrid>.subgrid-data>.tablediv>.ui-jqgrid>.ui-jqgrid-view>.ui-jqgrid-bdiv>div>.ui-jqgrid-btable");
                $subgrids.each(function () {
                    var grid = this.grid;
                    // we have subgrids which have no internal subgrids
                    // it reduce the number of columns to 1
                    // we have rownumbers: true in the main grid, but not in subgrids
                    // it reduce the number of columns to additional 1
                    // so we should use (index - 2) as the column index in the subgrids
                    grid.resizing = { idx: (index - 1) };
                    grid.headers[index - 1].newWidth = (index - 1 === 0) || (index === grid.headers.length) ? newWidth - 2 : newWidth;
                    grid.newWidth = grid.width + widthChange;
                    grid.dragEnd.call(grid);
                    $(this).jqGrid("setGridWidth", grid.newWidth, false);
                });
                $theGrid.jqGrid("setGridWidth", this.newWidth, false);
            }   

        });

        //$("#list").jqGrid("toggleSubGridRow", 'm1');
        //$("#list").jqGrid("toggleSubGridRow", 'm3');
    });

//]]>
</script>
```

I have few buttons like Next, Previous, Print, Export etc. below the grid.I have given a fix height to jqGrid. So, I can get vertical scroll bar.

I am using solution mentioned here. : [jqGrid horizontal scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091200/jqgrid-horizontal-scrollbar/4934612#4934612)

[image]

But, I am not able to re size last column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally find your question very interesting and I voted it up after I seen it before. The problem is that the solution of the problem isn't simple. One will have to modify the source code. I have no time currently for such implementation. Probably Tony will implement this. You can post the corresponding feature request to [trirand](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/).

The only thing which I can recommend you is the trick described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9599685/315935). It's not the same what you need, but it can improve users experience in some scenarios. I personally use it in the most productive grids which I made for my customers.

Nevertheless I can suggest you one workaround. Depend on other settings which you use the problem which you describe can be not so hard like it looks like. If you would use [gridResize](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods#resizable_grid) the user will be able to **resize the grid**. After increasing the size of the grid the user will be able to increase the width of the last column. If you use `shrinkToFit: false` or use

```
$("#gridId").jqGrid("gridResize", { shrinkToFit: false });
```

then the user will be able to resize the last column of the grid in two steps: 1) resize the grid 2) resize the last column of the grid.

**UPDATE:** The problem with resizing of the last column don't exist at all in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) starting with the version 4.9 (see [the readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README49.md#the-following-main-new-features-are-implemented-in-the-version-49)). Thus upgrading to the current version of free jqGrid (4.10.0 or higher) could resolve the problem with resizing of the last column of the grid.