# How to load data (json) in jqgrid via ajax?

Tags: ajax, json, jqgrid

i need to populate jqgrid after ajax's call.

I have a function (in java servelet) that returns this json format:

```
[{"citta":"XXXX","via":"XXX","telefono":"1111-11111","provincia":"XX","clienteDesc":"Prova","clienteCode":"XXXXX"}]
```

and i use this code for the jqgrid:

```
                $("#clienti-navgrid").jqGrid( { 
                            //data: c
                            //datatype: "local"
                            datatype: "json",
                url: '/project/loadnotespese.do',
                colNames:['Codice Cliente','Descrizone Cliente','Via','Città','Provincia','Telefono'],                
                colModel:[
                        {name:'clienteCode', index:'clienteCode', width:'10', sortable:false},  
                        {name:'clienteDesc', index:'clienteDesc', width:'20', sortable:false}, 
                        {name:'via', index:'via', width:'30', sortable:false},  
                        {name:'citta', index:'citta', width:'20', sortable:false},
                        {name:'provincia', index:'provincia', width:'10', sortable:false}, 
                        {name:'telefono', index:'telefono', width:'10', sortable:false} 
                ],
                rowNum:500,
                autowidth:true,
                height:'auto',
                recordtext:"Ordini trovati {2}",
                emptyrecords:"Nessun risultato",
                viewrecords: true,
                caption: 'Tabella Clienti',         
                localReader : {
                                    //
                    repeatitems: false,
                }
            });//jqGrid
```

if i put

```
var c = [{"citta":"XXXX","via":"XXX","telefono":"1111-11111","provincia":"XX","clienteDesc":"Prova","clienteCode":"XXXXX"}]
```

and

```
data: c, datatype: "local",
```

works, but if i'll get from url: '/project/loadnotespese.do', it dosen't work.
Any help?

Comment: I forgot to mention `root` in the `jsonReader`. See **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `datatype: "local"` the option `localReader` will be used. By the way the value `repeatitems: false` is *default* value for `localReader` (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#array_data)). So in case of usage `datatype: "local"` you can event remove the current option `localReader: { repeatitems: false }` from the list of the options.

On the other side if you use `datatype: "json"` *another option* `jsonReader` will be used. The default value of `repeatitems` property of `jsonReader` is `repeatitems: false` (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#json_data)). So you have to add

```js
jsonReader: { repeatitems: false }
```

in the case to the list of jqGrid options. After that the grid should be successfully filled.

One other important think which is important to know is specifying **additional** of `id` property in every item of the row of data. The `id` value must be unique over the whole page and it will be used as the value of `id` attributes of the rows (`<tr>`) elements of the grid body. If some other property of the row items can be used as the unique id you can either include additional setting in `jsonReader` or add `key: true` property in the corresponding definition of the column in `colModel`. For example if `clienteCode` can be interpreted as the rowid you can use

```js
jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, id: "clienteCode" }
```

**UPDATED**: You should use additionally

```js
root: function (obj) { return obj; }
```

inside of `jsonReader` (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#jsonreader_as_function)). So the final `jsonReader` should be

```js
jsonReader: {
    repeatitems: false,
    id: "clienteCode",
    root: function (obj) {
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi oleg, tks for reply. i'll set jsonReader : { repeatitems: false,id: "clienteCode"}, but still not fill the data in jqgrid

Comment: @GiacomoSavioli: Do you tried to use `root: function (obj) { return obj; }` (see updated part of my answer)

Comment: @Oleg: Can you help on this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684952/jqgrid-resize-last-column