# Horizontal scroll bar in jqgrid when needed

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid where there are 19 columns, I want to display full column headers and have a horizontal scroll bar (only when the the header columns exceed the `mainWidth`)

This is how I get my grids, but as you can see in **Database Version** panel all the 5 header columns are visible i want similar thing in **Database Release** panel but in this case as it will increase the width of the container so a horizontal scroll bar should appear displaying all the columns

[image]

Below is my code for the jqgrid

```
    var mainWidth=jQuery('#detailTable').width();

    panels+='<div title="Database Release" class="class">'+
                '<div class="jqUIDiv" style="width:'+mainWidth+'px; overflow-x:auto;">'+
                    '<table id="tblOrsDatabaseRelease" width="100%"></table>'+
                    '<div id="OrsDatabaseReleaseGridpager"></div>'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>';

    $('#detailTable').empty();
    $('<div>')
    .html('<div class="titleBlue">ORS Information</div>'+panels)
    .appendTo('#detailTable').delay(10).queue(function(){
        $('.class').jPanel({
            'effect'    : 'fade',
            'speed'     : 'slow',
            'easing'    : 'swing'
        });
    });
```

I am using [JPanel](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jPanel) (collapsible panels) above

```
    //Master Database Release
    jQuery("#tblOrsDatabaseRelease").jqGrid({
        datatype: "clientSide",
        colNames:['Debug Ind','Debug File Path','Debug Level','Debug File Name','LOG_FILE_SIZE','LOG_FILE_NUMBER','TNS_NAME','CONNECTION_PORT','ORACLE_SID','DATABASE_HOST','SCHEMA_WRITE_LOCK_DISABLED_IND','COLUMN_LENGTH_IN_BYTES_IND','MTIP_REGENERATION_REQUIRED_IND','GLOBAL_NOLOGGING_IND','PRODUCTION_MODE_IND','LAST_CHANGE_DATE','API_BATCH_INTEROP_IND','ZDT_IND','WORKFLOW_ENGINE_NAME'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'debugInd',index:'debugInd', align:"left"},   
            {name:'debugFilePath',index:'debugFilePath', align:"left"},
            {name:'debugLevel',index:'debugLevel', align:"left"},
            {name:'debugFileName',index:'debugFileName', align:"left"},
            {name:'LOG_FILE_SIZE',index:'LOG_FILE_SIZE', align:"left"},
            {name:'LOG_FILE_NUMBER',index:'LOG_FILE_NUMBER', align:"left"},
            {name:'TNS_NAME',index:'TNS_NAME', align:"left"},
            {name:'CONNECTION_PORT',index:'CONNECTION_PORT', align:"left"},
            {name:'ORACLE_SID',index:'ORACLE_SID', align:"left"},
            {name:'DATABASE_HOST',index:'DATABASE_HOST', align:"left"},
            {name:'SCHEMA_WRITE_LOCK_DISABLED_IND',index:'SCHEMA_WRITE_LOCK_DISABLED_IND', align:"left"},
            {name:'COLUMN_LENGTH_IN_BYTES_IND',index:'COLUMN_LENGTH_IN_BYTES_IND', align:"left"},
            {name:'MTIP_REGENERATION_REQUIRED_IND',index:'MTIP_REGENERATION_REQUIRED_IND', align:"left"},
            {name:'GLOBAL_NOLOGGING_IND',index:'GLOBAL_NOLOGGING_IND', align:"left"},
            {name:'PRODUCTION_MODE_IND',index:'PRODUCTION_MODE_IND', align:"left"},
            {name:'LAST_CHANGE_DATE',index:'LAST_CHANGE_DATE', align:"left"},
            {name:'API_BATCH_INTEROP_IND',index:'API_BATCH_INTEROP_IND', align:"left"},
            {name:'ZDT_IND',index:'ZDT_IND', align:"left"},
            {name:'WORKFLOW_ENGINE_NAME',index:'WORKFLOW_ENGINE_NAME', align:"left"}
        ],
        pagination:true,
        pager : '#OrsDatabaseReleaseGridpager',
        rowNum:10,
        rowList:[10,50,100],
        scrollOffset:0,
        height: 'auto',
        autowidth:true,
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        edit:false,
        add:false,
        del:false,
        loadComplete: function() {
            var gr = jQuery('#tblOrsDatabaseRelease');
            fixGridWidth(gr);
        }
    });
    for(var i=0;i<orsDbRelease.length;i++)
        jQuery("#tblOrsDatabaseRelease").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,orsDbRelease[i]);
    jQuery("#tblOrsDatabaseRelease").setGridParam({rowNum:10}).trigger("reloadGrid
```

I used [Oleg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686043/correctly-calling-setgridwidth-on-a-jqgrid-inside-a-jqueryui-dialog/2696776#2696776) to get the below function

```
    var fixGridWidth = function (grid) {
        var gviewScrollWidth = grid[0].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.scrollWidth;
        var mainWidth = jQuery('#detailTable').width();
        var gridScrollWidth = grid[0].scrollWidth;
        var htable = jQuery('table.ui-jqgrid-htable', grid[0].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode);
        var scrollWidth = gridScrollWidth;
        if (htable.length > 0) {
            var hdivScrollWidth = htable[0].scrollWidth;
            if ((gridScrollWidth < hdivScrollWidth))
                scrollWidth = hdivScrollWidth; // max (gridScrollWidth, hdivScrollWidth)
        }
        if (gviewScrollWidth != scrollWidth || scrollWidth > mainWidth) {
            var newGridWidth = (scrollWidth <= mainWidth)? scrollWidth: mainWidth;  // min (scrollWidth, mainWidth)
            // if the grid has no data, gridScrollWidth can be less then hdiv[0].scrollWidth
            if (newGridWidth != gviewScrollWidth)
                grid.jqGrid("setGridWidth", newGridWidth);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose that the problem which you have exists because of misunderstanding of different parameters of jqGrid which defines column width. To tell the trust there are many scenarios of the width choosing and you are not the only person who don't full understand the possibilities of choosing width of grid and columns in jqGrid.

You wrote

> I have a jqgrid where there are 19 columns, I want to display full
>   column headers and have a horizontal scroll bar.

To implement the requirements you need do following

- remove `autowidth: true` option of jqGrid.
- add `shrinkToFit: false` option of jqGrid.
- add `width` property in every column of `colModel`. If you don't specify any `width` value for the column the default value `width: 150` You should choose the width which you really need to see. The width value will be not changed by jqGrid because you use `shrinkToFit: false`.
- you should not use and value for `width` option of jqGrid. In the case the grid width will be the sum of the widths of all columns of the grid.
- remove call of `fixGridWidth` from `loadComplete`. I suppose you will not need the function at all.

I don't use JPanel plugin and don't see any advantage of the plugin comparing to [jQuery UI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#collapsible) widget. Probably there are some issues specific for JPanel plugin. Nevertheless I suppose that you should remove `width="100%"` attribute from the `<table>` element which you will use as grid.

I can't test my suggestions in your environment, but I hope it is very close to what you need.

Some common remarks to your code:

- there are no options `pagination`, `edit`, `add` or `del` in jqGrid. You should remove the parameters.
- to fill the grid with data you should add `data: orsDbRelease` parameter to jqGrid and remove the usage of `addRowData` in the loop and `reloadGrid` after the loop. If you use `data` parameter the grid will be filled more quickly and will have already correct pagination.
- the default value of the property `align` in items of the `colModel` is already 'left' (see the value in the column "Default" in the table from [the page](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options) of documentation). So you can remove the property `align:"left"` from every column.
- You should consider to include `sorttype` property for all non-text column in the grid. It will make the sort order of the corresponding column correctly. Probably the usage of different `formatter` properties can additionally improve the visibility of the grid. See [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter#predefined_format_types) for more details.

Comment: Every one of you answers are incredible, thank you for sharing your knowledge of jqgrid.

Answer (score 0):

I would second the above answer by Oleg, but jPanel does not cause any problems here and I have tested that and the advantage of jPanel over accordion is that you can have multiple panels open at once and it uses minimal mark up and the latest version has many other features too you can check it out and review here https://sites.google.com/site/jqpanel/home do let me know your valuable comments.

As for your code plz remove the delay and queue function it may be causing an issue use it as below instead

```
$('#detailTable').empty();
$('<div>')
.html('<div class="titleBlue">ORS Information</div>'+panels)
.appendTo('#detailTable').find('.class').jPanel({
        'effect'    : 'fade',
        'speed'     : 'slow',
        'easing'    : 'swing'
    });
```