# Can we add jqgrid options dynamically?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a doubt in Jqgrid. Can anyone tell me,is It possible to add options like 'shrinkToFit:false' or someother options dynamically in Jqgrid.

Can anyone tell how it can be done?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

If you look at jqGrid [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options), you will see that there is a column (last one) which is named *Can be changed?*. This column tells you if the option value can be set\changed after jqGrid initialization. This column in most cases takes one of following values:

- **No** - the option value can't be set\changed after intialization
- **No. Method avail.** - there is a special method dedicated for changing this option, the jqGrid methods documentation can be found [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods).
- **Yes** - the option value can be set\changed with `setGridParam` method like this:

  $('#gridId').jqGrid('setGridParam', { autoencode: true });
- **Yes. Requires reload** - the option value can be set\changed with `setGridParam` method but jqGrid needs to be reloaded in order to use new value. This can be achieved like this:

  $('#gridId').jqGrid('setGridParam', { altRows: true }).trigger('reloadGrid');

I hope this explains the subject in general.

If it comes to `shrinkToFit` options its value can't be set\changed after intialization - you would need to destroy the grid and built it again.

Comment: Thanks alot. But I have a requirement with jqgrid as I need to add columns using column chooser,so that If I add columns grid size is increasing,sometimes I may get columns like 40.So what I can do now.How to get horizontal scroll if width of jqgrid exceeds. So I tried to use shrinkToFit,but it didnt worked :(

Comment: @user1268130 Well your requirement is pretty far away from the question you have asked. I suggest you ask a new question which describes your scenario in details so comunity can look into it. This question was answered accordingly to its content. Also I suggest you read this question before starting new one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292341/horizontal-scroll-bar-in-jqgrid-when-needed

Comment: Sorry I always forget about this.I got my answer,Now I know how to cal setGridParam :)

Comment: When it says `no method-avail` where do I find the method that is available?

Comment: @KolobCanyon You need to go through the documentation, what is the setting you are looking for?

Comment: @tpeczek I do need to read more carefully through the documentation