# how can I adjust jqGrid rows/columns to fill 100% of ths space?

Tags: jqgrid

my jqGrid columns don't fill all of the grid space.
I've read some questions, found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686043/correctly-calling-setgridwidth-on-a-jqgrid-inside-a-jqueryui-dialog/2696776#2696776), but it didn't work for me.

when the page loads, the grid looks like this:

[image: jqGrid columns don't fill all the space]

I'd be very grateful if someone could help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem should not exist in the old form described in [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686043/correctly-calling-setgridwidth-on-a-jqgrid-inside-a-jqueryui-dialog/2696776#2696776). If you would use `height: "auto"` or would use `scrollOffset: 0` then the free space on the right side will be not visible. The default options used in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) (it's the fork which I develop) are changed a little(see [readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md) and [wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki)). So that one can create the grid with less options and to have less problems like the problem in your question.

The free space on the right size exist typically because one use default options of jqGrid. The width of the free space corresponds the size of `scrollOffset` option which have *static* value in jqGrid. Free jqGrid instead (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.base.js#L893)) set it dynamically inside of internal method `fixScrollOffsetAndhBoxPadding` which will be called inside of other internal methods `finalReportSteps` or `finalReportVirtual` at the end of every filling of the grid. So one will typically don't have the problems at all.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention the version difference. but "height: 'auto'" and "scrollOffset: 0" solved the problem. thank you so much, Oleg!

Comment: Also, I was supposed to change my jqGrid version last week and I didn't. That was obviously a mistake, so I'm doing it now. Thanks again!