# How to both resize and minimize a jqGrid table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm building an application which needs to handle very large amounts of text, and where screen space for viewing it is at a premium.  Being able to resize and/or minimize a table with jqGrid seems an ideal solution...only I have not been able to get it to work.  I can do one or the other, but not both.  With both options enabled, after the first resize event, the minimize will only blank out, leaving a border behind which occupies the prior dimensions of the table.

I'm new to jQuery and jqGrid, so I have not been able to grasp the concepts enough to understand what is going wrong.  I found a similar issue discussed [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870463/make-a-jqgrid-moveable) where a work-around was posted, but I have not gotten the workaround to work for me.  (It's probably something super simple, but I just can't see it yet.)

Thanks so much for helping.

Here's the workaround (that I haven't gotten to work):

```
//
// Make the grid resizable.
//
$("#treegrid2").jqGrid('gridResize',{minWidth:350,minHeight:150,
  stop: function (grid, ev, ui) {
    $(grid.srcElement).parent ().css ("height", null);
  }
});
```

And here's my code so far:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="Source-Info" content="http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules" />
<title>My Grid One</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="./css/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="./css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="./css/ui.multiselect.css" />

<style>
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 75%;
}
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
    white-space: normal !important;
    height:auto;
    vertical-align:text-top;
    padding-top:2px;
}
</style> 


<script src="./js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="grid.loader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.tablednd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.contextmenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery.layout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./js/grid.formedit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./js/ui.multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>


<body>
<script src="celledit.js" type="text/javascript"> </script> 

<table id="repost"></table> 
<div id="prepost"></div> 
<input type="BUTTON" id="bedata" value="Edit Selected" /> 
<div id="hiddenDivId"></div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#repost").jqGrid({
    url:'example.php',
    editurl: 'jqGridCrud.php', // 'update_mysql.php'
    mtype: 'GET',
    forceFit : true,
    cellEdit: true,
    cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
    beforeSaveCell: function() {
        //rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol
        //alert(arguments[0]+' '+arguments[1]+' '+arguments[2])
$.post("jqGridCrud.php", {id: arguments[0], col: arguments[1], query: arguments[2]},
   function(data){
});

    },
    onclickSubmit: function (params) {
        var ajaxData = {};
        var list = $("#repost");
        var selectedRow = list.getGridParam("selrow");
        rowData = list.getRowData(selectedRow);
        ajaxData = { invid: rowData.invid };
        alert("GOT IT");
        return ajaxData;
    },
    colNames:['Inv No','Date','Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
    colModel :[ 
      {name:'invid', index:'invid', width:55,editable:false}, 
      {name:'invdate', index:'invdate', width:60,editable:true},
      {name:'amount', index:'amount', width:60, align:'right',editable:true}, 
      {name:'tax', index:'tax', width:60, align:'right',editable:true}, 
      {name:'total', index:'total', width:60, align:'right',editable:true}, 
      {name:'note', index:'note', width:350, edittype:'textarea', editoptions: {rows:"10"},sortable:false,editable:true} 
    ],
    rowNum:10,
    width:700,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    multiselect: false,
    pager: '#prepost',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortname: 'invid',
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption:"My Own Grid",
    stop: function (grid, ev, ui) {
        $(grid.srcElement).parent().css ("height", null);
      },
    onHeaderClick: function (grid, ev, ui) {
        $(grid.srcElement).parent().css ("height", null);
      }

});

$("#bedata").click(function(){ var gr = jQuery("#repost").getGridParam('selrow'); //getSelectedRow(); 
//if( gr != null ) jQuery("#repost").delGridRow(gr,{reloadAfterSubmit:false}); else alert("Please Select Row to delete!"); 
 var rows= jQuery("#repost").jqGrid('getRowData');
  var paras=new Array();
  for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
      var row=rows[i];
      paras.push($.param(row));
  }

  alert (paras);

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "jqGridCrud.php",
      data: paras.join(),
      success: function(msg){          alert('MESS:'+msg+" END:\n\n"+paras);      }

  });

//get total rows in the grid
 var numberOfRecords = $("#repost").getGridParam("invid");
 for(i=1;i<=numberOfRecords;i++)
{

    var rowId = $("#repost").getRowData(i);
    var name = rowId['name'];

              //put all rows for the grid
    $('<input type="hidden" />').attr('name', i+'_name').attr('value',ime).appendTo('#hiddenDivId');
};

}); 

jQuery("#repost").jqGrid('navGrid','#prepost',{edit:false,add:false,del:false,drag:true});
jQuery("#repost").jqGrid('gridResize',{minWidth:350,maxWidth:800,minHeight:80, maxHeight:350});

    //
    // Make the grid resizable.
    //
jQuery("#repost").jqGrid('gridResize',{minWidth:350,minHeight:150,
      stop: function (grid, ev, ui) {
        $(grid.srcElement).parent ().css ("height", null);
      }
    }); 

 //$('#gbox_repost').draggable (); // Drags from anywhere in the grid, not just title bar :(
 $('#gbox_' + 'repost').draggable ({handle:"div.ui-jqgrid-titlebar"});


// $(document).ready(function() {
  //   $('#repost').editable('jqGridCrud.php');
// });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: AS OF 23 May, I'm still looking for answers on this one!  If anyone has solved this riddle, please provide the rest of us the solution.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution to resizing the grid, and it seems to work with resizing:

```
$(window).bind('resize', function () {
    var width = $("#myGrid").closest('.grid_container').width() - 2; // fudging to prevent scrollbars
    $("#myGrid").('setGridWidth', width);
}).trigger('resize');
```

The '.grid_container' selector selects the div which I've wrapped around the grid specifically for resizing purposes (and any other styles I need to add).

However, I can see how you using "min-height" instead of just "height" might make the minimization fail.

You may be able to expand my code about to adjust the height of the grid as well.... but I wouldn't recommend it. You should probably just allow the grid to fit the amount of rows it has listed, and then restrict the amount of rows per page.

Comment: Thank you for your response, xixonia.  I tried adding your suggested code, but found I could no longer resize at all.  When I looked at the javascript errors, it now said "XML filter is applied to non-XML value" and pointed to this line as the source of the error:

        $("#repost").('setGridWidth', width);

Comment: interesting. What version of jqGrid are you using? Also, did you add a surrounding div with the "grid_container" class?

Comment: Thank you again for your time and help, xixonia.  I had added the div, but not the "grid_container" class.  I now added that (I think) via <div id="depost" class="grid_container">, and now, interestingly, I can resize the grid, but still cannot move it and still see the same XML-related error.  I don't know what version of jqGrid I have, but I downloaded it within the past couple of months.

Comment: This is quite odd... I don't know what to say about the "non-XML value" error... :/