# jqGrid Top Toolbar

Tags: jqgrid

I am trying to replicate the action buttons that are present in the bottom toolbar on the top toolbar.

But so far no luck, I have included the truncated code below.

Paging is not an option in this case so the user requires both top and bottom toolbars.

```
jQuery("#GridName").jqGrid({
    url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~") %>SomeController/SomeMethod ....',
    datatype: 'json',
    colNames: ['Column1', 'Column2',  'Details', 'Date'],
    colModel: [
        //......
    ],
    pager: '#GridNamePager',
    viewrecords: true,
    emptyrecords: "Nothing to display",
    shrinkToFit: true,
    hidegrid: false,
    scroll: false,
    width: 976,
    height: 'auto',
    loadui: 'enable',
    pgtext: '',
    pgbuttons: false,
    pginput: false,
    multiselect: true,
    multiboxonly: true,
    toolbar:[true,"top"],
    ondblClickRow: function(id) {
        var publishedUrl =
           $("#GridName").find("tbody")[0].rows[id-1].cells[5].innerHTML;
    },
    caption: "Grid Results"
}).navGrid('#GridNamePager', { add: false, edit: false, del: false,
                               search: false, cloneToTop:true })
  .navButtonAdd('#GridNamePager', { caption: "Save", onClickButton:
             function() { Save(); return false; }, position: "last" })
  .navButtonAdd('#GridNamePager', { caption: "Back", onClickButton:
             function() { redirectBack(); return false; }, position: "last" })
```

where

```
<table id="GridName" class="scroll"></table>
<div id="GridnamePager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the answer [Adding button to jqGrid top toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678904/adding-button-to-jqgrid-top-toolbar) would helps you? If not try to explain more exactly which elements of navigation bar or other jqGrid elements you would be move to another place.

Comment: Want to replicate the folowing at bottom and top of grid

.navGrid('#GridNamePager', { add: false, edit: false, del: false,
                               search: false, cloneToTop:true })
  .navButtonAdd('#GridNamePager', { caption: "Save", onClickButton:
             function() { Save(); return false; }, position: "last" })
  .navButtonAdd('#GridNamePager', { caption: "Back", onClickButton:
             function() { redirectBack(); return false; }, position: "last" })

Comment: @Spanner: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929896/adding-jqgrid-custom-navigation-to-top-toolbar/3932314#3932314. It seems that the solution is what you need.