# can you replicate all buttons on the top in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

i see in jqgrid you can move the pager up to the top of the grid and the default buttons but i wanted to see if you can move the entire row (including buttons default and custom along with the pager) to the top above the grid ?

if i use clonetoTop it only moves the regular buttons but not ones that i add dynamically

### Update:

---

As you can see below, i added my own personal RefreshGrid button using this code and its not showing up at top:

```
 .navButtonAdd('#pager', {
            caption: "",
            title: "Reload Grid",
            buttonicon: "ui-icon-refresh",
            onClickButton: function () {
                $(gridSelector).trigger("reloadGrid");
            },
            position: "last"
        });
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter `cloneToTop:true` of the `navGrid` do what you need:

```
$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {cloneToTop: true});
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402455/unable-to-position-pager-navigation-bar-above-jqgrid/4402903#4402903) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552855/add-toolbar-in-the-bottom-of-the-header-using-jqgrid/3557663#3557663) for additional information.

Comment: that doesn't seem to copy the custom button to the top. I have put a screenshot in the question after adding cloneToTop to show you the issue. As you can see the refresh grid button that i added is not being cloned

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929896/adding-jqgrid-custom-navigation-to-top-toolbar/3932314#3932314) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518646/add-buttons-to-a-new-top-toolbar/5524152#5524152) you will find the corresponding examples. Because the `navButtonAdd` should be called **after** the `navGrid` the `navGrid` clone only the buttons which exist at the moment. So you should just use `mygrid.jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#'+mygrid[0].id+"_toppager", options)` to add custom button to the toppager.