# Adding drop down menus to jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, jquery-ui-menu

I'm working on porting a WinForm app to the browser and would like to retain the ability to have a set of drop down menus along the top (within the Toolbar) of jqGrid.

I'm able to create a [custom toolbar](http://blog.anupamgupta.me/2010/01/adding-buttons-in-jqgrid-toolbar/) for the top of the grid w/o cloning the bottom and thus have action buttons. I'm also able to [clone the existing navigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678904/adding-button-to-jqgrid-top-toolbar).

What I'm missing is how to have either of these two options incorporate a menu system such as [jQuery UI Menu](http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/). The below code will add the menu to the toolbar but the menu then becomes hidden behind the grid. I've tried adjusting the z-index and position but neither appeared to resolve it.

```
toolbar: [true,'top'];
...
$("#toolbarId").append('<ul id="myMenu"><li><a href="#">File</a><ul><li>'+
'<a href="#">New</a></li><li><a href="#">Delete</a></li></ul></li></ul>');
$("#myMenu").menu();
```

Any help is appreciated. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use [position](http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/#option-position) option of [jQuery UI Menu Widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/). You can use `using` callback (see documentation of [jQuery UI Position](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/)) to change properties of submenu.

Just try for example

```
$("#myMenu").menu({position: {
    of: "#gview_" + $grid[0].id,
    my: "left top",
    at: "left top",
    using: function (props, feedback) {
        $(this).css({top: (props.top + 25), left: (props.left + 50), zIndex: 1005});
    }
}}).css("width", "50px");
```

where `var $grid = $("#grid");` - your grid. You will see the possibilities which you have.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. Worked perfectly. I also found that it helps to have my jquery-ui.css at the same version of my jquery-ui.js. :$